# Старый бородаты вопрос - как спозиционировать объект внутри дива.

Tags: css

Доброго всем кодинга.
Почему объект (картинка или что-либо др.) выскакивает из DIV'а, когда на него применяется 
"position: absolute;"
[пример тут](http://jsfiddle.net/AAwbw/)
Хотя либо div, либо img уже в контейнере и являются дочерними от общего DIV'a
Если убрать с часов "position: absolute;", то он опять залезет в DIV.

---

Вопрос: как спозиционировать объект внутри DIV'а, что бы он не выскакивал из него?
"float:right;" - делает тоже самое.
[А хотелось бы как тут, только вот что-бы часы справа были](http://jsfiddle.net/AAwbw/1/)

Comment: `position: absolute` ведет отсчет относительно ближайшего родителя с нестатичным позиционированием. Достаточно задать родителю `position: relative`.

Comment: Так и не разобрался.  
Если ставлю дочерним (некоторым) объектам absolute, то родительский "выбрасывает" из себя объекты, картинки, DIV'ы, "схлапывается" и приходилось прописывать ему жёсткую высоту.  
А если ставлю одному из дочерних relative, то все объекты с DIV'ами ведут себя адекватно.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Npe76/

HTML

```
<div class="top-left"><iframe src='http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i3rul6zn/n372/szw100/szh100/hocfff/hbw0/cf100/hgr0/fas20/fdi72/mqc000/mql10/mqw4/mqd98/mhc000/mhl10/mhw4/mhd98/mmc444/mml5/mmw1/mmd98/hwm2/hhs2/hhl55/hhb16/hhr5/hms2/hml70/hmb16/hmr7/hsl80/hsb16/hsr5' frameborder='0' width='102' height='102'></iframe></div>

<div class="top-right"><iframe src='http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i3rul6zn/n372/szw100/szh100/hocfff/hbw0/cf100/hgr0/fas20/fdi72/mqc000/mql10/mqw4/mqd98/mhc000/mhl10/mhw4/mhd98/mmc444/mml5/mmw1/mmd98/hwm2/hhs2/hhl55/hhb16/hhr5/hms2/hml70/hmb16/hmr7/hsl80/hsb16/hsr5' frameborder='0' width='102' height='102'></iframe></div>

<div class="bottom-left"><iframe src='http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i3rul6zn/n372/szw100/szh100/hocfff/hbw0/cf100/hgr0/fas20/fdi72/mqc000/mql10/mqw4/mqd98/mhc000/mhl10/mhw4/mhd98/mmc444/mml5/mmw1/mmd98/hwm2/hhs2/hhl55/hhb16/hhr5/hms2/hml70/hmb16/hmr7/hsl80/hsb16/hsr5' frameborder='0' width='102' height='102'></iframe></div>

<div class="bottom-right"><iframe src='http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i3rul6zn/n372/szw100/szh100/hocfff/hbw0/cf100/hgr0/fas20/fdi72/mqc000/mql10/mqw4/mqd98/mhc000/mhl10/mhw4/mhd98/mmc444/mml5/mmw1/mmd98/hwm2/hhs2/hhl55/hhb16/hhr5/hms2/hml70/hmb16/hmr7/hsl80/hsb16/hsr5' frameborder='0' width='102' height='102'></iframe></div>

<div class="center-center"><iframe src='http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i3rul6zn/n372/szw100/szh100/hocfff/hbw0/cf100/hgr0/fas20/fdi72/mqc000/mql10/mqw4/mqd98/mhc000/mhl10/mhw4/mhd98/mmc444/mml5/mmw1/mmd98/hwm2/hhs2/hhl55/hhb16/hhr5/hms2/hml70/hmb16/hmr7/hsl80/hsb16/hsr5' frameborder='0' width='102' height='102'></iframe></div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    border: 2px solid #c00;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fceabb; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fceabb 0%, #fccd4d 50%, #f8b500 51%, #fbdf93 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fceabb), color-stop(50%,#fccd4d), color-stop(51%,#f8b500), color-stop(100%,#fbdf93)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fceabb 0%,#fccd4d 50%,#f8b500 51%,#fbdf93 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fceabb 0%,#fccd4d 50%,#f8b500 51%,#fbdf93 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fceabb 0%,#fccd4d 50%,#f8b500 51%,#fbdf93 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fceabb 0%,#fccd4d 50%,#f8b500 51%,#fbdf93 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fceabb', endColorstr='#fbdf93',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.top-left iframe{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
.top-right iframe{position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}
.bottom-left iframe{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;}
.bottom-right iframe{position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;}
.center-center iframe{
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -52px 0 0 -52px;
}
```

Comment: В вашем примере попробуйте убрать жёсткую высоту родителя:(min-height: 200px;)
И получите мою ситуацию.